# How to implement a logger that appends to a file?

Tags: logging, rust

I'm trying to implement `log::Log` such that the call to `log()` appends the message to a file. This is my logger at the moment:

```
pub struct MyLogger {
    loglevel: LogLevelFilter,
    logfile: Option<File>,
}
```

And the implementation of log::Log:

```
impl Log for Logger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
        metadata.level() <= self.loglevel
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
        if self.enabled(record.metadata()) {
            let msg = format!("{}\t| {}\t| {}", record.level(), record.target(), record.args());
            self.logfile.write_all(msg.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Which, understandably, fails because `log()` doesn't take a mutable reference. I can't take a mutable reference because then I wouldn't be implementing the type correctly, so what would be the idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you need to present a non-mutable interface but do mutation behind the scenes, you can use *interior mutability*. The common way of doing this is with something from [`std::cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html). The docs call out this specific usecase:

> because you must employ mutation to implement a trait method that was originally defined to take &self.

Specifically, I'd try to use [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) in this case.

Unfortunately, [`Log`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/trait.Log.html) requires the implementer to also be `Sync + Send`, but cells are not. That means we need to upgrade to something that can handle multiple threads. That something is [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html):

```
extern crate log;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use log::{LogLevelFilter,LogMetadata,LogRecord,Log};

pub struct FileLogger {
    loglevel: LogLevelFilter,
    logfile: Option<Mutex<File>>,
}

impl Log for FileLogger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
        metadata.level() <= self.loglevel
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
        if self.enabled(record.metadata()) {
            let msg = format!("{}\t| {}\t| {}", record.level(), record.target(), record.args());
            self.logfile.as_ref().map(|f| {
                f.lock().unwrap().write_all(msg.as_bytes()).unwrap()
            });
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
}
```

Comment: Note: have synchronous I/O in the thread calling `log` is generally not desired, as a result it is common to use an internal queue or buffer and have a dedicated "consumer" thread in charge of writing to the files. In the Rust world, maybe a channel?